# How to find floor of $ 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} + ...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2017}}$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to find floor of $S=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} + ...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2017}}$?

With
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} > 2(\sqrt{i+1} -\sqrt{i})$$
and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} < 2(\sqrt{i} -\sqrt{i-1}),$$
I'm able to get to
$$2 \sqrt{n+1}-2 < \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} < 2 \sqrt{n}-1.$$

Given $n=2017$, the result is $88.37282...$ (using [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=sum+n+from+1+to+2017+of+Divide%5B1%2CSqrt%5Bn%5D%5D)), so the floor should be $88$.
But I just get to $87.844<S<88.822$, and therefore I don't get the exact floor.
With ALGEBRA ONLY (no integral, limit, Harmonic Series), could you please help me to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Keep the first few terms as they are and estimate the tail via $
2(\sqrt {2018}  - \sqrt m ) < \sum\limits_{k = m}^{2017} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }}}  < 2(\sqrt {2017}  - \sqrt {m - 1} )
$ with a suitable $m$.

Comment: Similar questions https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540420/1012971 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826197/floor-sum-of-reciprocal-of-square-root-of-first-50-numbers?noredirect=1 and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1892199p12914972

Comment: Thank you @Gary, I've solved this with your help!

Comment: Thank you @RamanujanXV, I did a search, but they all used integral which is not allowed in solution.

Comment: @longnh So make an answer based on Gray's help in below. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Gary's help, I'm able to solve this problem. Thank you!
With $k≥1$, we have: 
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k}} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k-1}} $$
So
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k-1}} $$
and so
$$ 2(\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < 2(\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k-1})$$

- With $k=2$: $ 2(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < 2(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1})$
- With $k=3$: $ 2(\sqrt{4} - \sqrt{3}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} < 2(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2})$ 
  ...
- With $k=2017$: $ 2(\sqrt{2018} - \sqrt{2017}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2017}} < 2(\sqrt{2017} - \sqrt{2016})$ 
  So we have:
  $1 + 2(\sqrt{2018} - \sqrt{2}) < S < 1 + 2(\sqrt{2017} - 1)$ 
  And therefore $88.016<S<88.822$ which implies that $$\lfloor S\rfloor = 88.$$

Comment: Same approach as here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1826218/42969, and that does *not* use integrals.